My for-loop (in c language) is not looping in vscode
In my code below, I'm trying to check whether each char in the string array is alphabetical or not by creating a bool function. But when I run the program, my bool function is not looping through the string array and only checks the first char in the string array. Further debugging also shows that the function is indeed not looping through the string array.
p.s this is a test i made for a CS50 problem.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>


bool only_alpha(string a);

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("String: ");

    if(only_alpha(s))
    {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No\n");
    }
}

bool only_alpha(string a)
{
    int q = strlen(a);

    //check if each char in string is alphabetical
    
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(a[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


this is what i get when I run the program.
enter image description here
I've used for-loops before and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I'm starting to think it's a VScode problem (after a new update) because I've used this exact code (but with isdigits).
Please help!!!

What is string in your code? Did you typedef it before?

@ImanAbdollahzadeh It's a CS50 facepalm thing. They teach newbies to do typedef char* string;... and yes that's horrible.

Please add text as formatted text in your question instead of showing a picture or plain text.

Now is a really good time to break the habit of one letter variable names. Use something meaningful instead. Your code will be better for it.

No images of text please

oh i see, you are returning a bool from the function only_alpha too early. Right now, it's going to check if the the first char of string a[0] is alphabetical or not? if not? based on user input it will return a true/false and immediately end the loop.
Replace the loop w this instead:
bool only_alpha(string a)
{
    int q = strlen(a);

    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(a[i]))
        {
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true; 
}


The logic is wrong, you always return upon checking the first letter, regardless of what it was. Instead you should return upon the first invalid letter, or if no invalid ones were found, return true at the end:
for(int i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    if(!isalpha(a[i]))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;

